# missing scope error slack message from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

If I run the following script to send a message from slack I get a missing scope error, which I cannot resolve so far!

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

from slack import WebClient
from slack.errors import SlackApiError

slack_token = 'xoxb-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx'
client = WebClient(token=slack_token)

try:
  response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel="C018KGV8GHJ",
    text="Hello from your app! :tada:"
  )
except SlackApiError as e:
   #You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
   assert e.response["error"]  # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
```

I receive the following error: 'ok': False, 'error': 'missing_scope', 'needed': 'chat:write:bot', 'provided': 'incoming-webhook'

The script is from the slack webpage.

How can I solve the missing_scope error?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was how I set up the slack API. I reinstalled the API: incoming webhooks needs to be enabled, in permissions: Channel:Read and Chat:Write needs to be activated. Also the API needs to be added to the channel. After this everything worked fine!